# Class java.io.FileNotFoundException on reading a text file from android sdcard

Tags: java, android, filenotfoundexception

How to read a .txt file from sdcard.I tried the following method but it returns empty string saying file not found exception

---

```
public String ReadFile(){

        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File file = new File(sdcard,"/folder/json.txt");
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                text.append(line);
                text.append('\n');
            }
            br.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            //You'll need to add proper error handling here
            Toast.makeText(this, "No data exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        String flag=text.toString();
        return flag;
    }
```

---

ERROR:/storage/emulated/0/folder/json.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: If you are running in M or above, need to check permission allowed during runtime. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39011657/permission-denied-but-permission-is-set-in-manifest/39011907#39011907

Comment: but i am using L for testing

Comment: can anyone help me to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is tips from me :

1. Make sure the file is really exist, show the print out file URI.
2. Make sure the read external permission is already **added** on Manifest file.
3. Run on the real device, not on Emulator.

Comment: 1.file exist in phone memory. 2.permission added:    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>  3.tested on real devices

Comment: Is the file on SDCard or  Internal phone storage ?
AFAIK, your code are to access SDCard not internal phone storage.

Comment: please refer to this  [link](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/06/android-internal-external-storage.html) for more details

Comment: the file is in external storage.i can see the file in file manager-> folder->json.txt file